# How to get same effect as like %someword% with match-against in MySQL with using solr etc

Tags: php, mysql, solr, sql-like, match-against

Possible Duplicate of: [How to use prefix wildcards like '*abc' with match-against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848445/how-to-use-prefix-wildcards-like-abc-with-match-against)

But i cannot find my answer so asked this question sorry for the duplicate.

I am performing a query in MySQL

Records are :

1. I am john doe.
2. John doe is a man.
3. John last name is doe

like **%john d%** will match first two result because they are in same order and wilds will match it any where in the record
But in a large data set this has killed the performance

So i googled and found **MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE**
as an alternative.Now,
my search term is: john d
It tried

```
AGAINST('"john d"')
AGAINST('john d*')
AGAINST('+john +d') etc
```

I only want to get results that are in same order.
(e.g 1. i am john doe. 2. john doe is a man) for this search term john d but i cannot achieve it.  **like %john d%** gives my desired but  it kills the performance.
how can i get my desired result in MySQL with fast performance.

In Possible Duplicate of: [How to use prefix wildcards like '*abc' with match-against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848445/how-to-use-prefix-wildcards-like-abc-with-match-against)

**@GolezTrol** gave a solution to create a separate column in which he reverse the strings:

```
user_login user_login_rev
xyzabc     cbazyx
```

Then, instead of looking for **'%john d'**, we can look for 'john d%' which is much faster if the column is indexed.

But

**@PeerBr** Bewares that inverting strings will not help you if you want to find stuff from the middle of the string. You won't find **"Jimmy Blue Jones"** by typing **'Blue%'** using normal indices nor by inverting **'Blue%'** using inverted inices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Solr this should work nicely with a field [with a KeywordTokenizer and a ReverseWildcardFilter](http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/):

```
<fieldType name="c_string" class="solr.TextField">
 <analyzer type="index">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" />
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Depending on your use case you can drop the ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory. The LowerCaseFilterFactory ensures that the string is lowercase properly, while the KeywordTokenizer keeps the whole string as a single token - so that you don't match case #3 in your examples.

The ReversedWildcardFilter stores the tokens in reversed order as well, and when it detects a prefix wildcard, it appends a reversed token prefix search as well, so you still get good performance from the indexed tokens.

Comment: any suggestions without solr