# About FullText Index Search

Tags: mysql

I,m tryin using FullText on mysql 5.6 innodb
I nees a query like:

```
select * from table_name where col like '%xamp%'
```

I try:

```
select * from table_name where MATCH(col) AGAINST ("*xamp*")
```

But don't work

I need search all words that has "xamp",

If I use:

```
select * from table_name where MATCH(col) AGAINST ("example")
```

Works fine.

is possible do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use prefix wildcards like '\*abc' with match-against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848445/how-to-use-prefix-wildcards-like-abc-with-match-against)

Comment: I don't think that full-text search can do that—it's a technique explicitly designed to work on natural text.

Answer (score 0):

FullText Index Search dont work using partial words